# Meaning of "almost a lifetime since"

Tags: meaning

I am not able to comprehend the meaning of "**almost a lifetime since**" used in the following sentence:

> **Almost a lifetime since**, he had been elected an MLA twice and an MP four times from Hyderabad, a seat that his father Sultan Salahuddin Owaisi represented six times. He has recast the archetype for Muslim leadership. Does he regret giving up law to be a lawmaker? “Regret…? I don’t know... It is a very subjective thing. I don’t regret things in life, you look at the good side of it and go ahead,” Mr. Owaisi said.

[Link of the full article](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/telangana/asaddudin-owaisi-the-champion-of-identity-politics/article33100558.ece)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Since" here is a formal or old-fashioned synonym for "ago". The phrase should be understood as "almost a lifetime ago".
See https://www.lexico.com/definition/since (adverb, 2).

Answer (score 1):

Since it's right at the beginning of a new paragraph you shall refer to a preceding one in order to apprehend its meaning. And the preceding states:

> The young Owaisi, who wanted to be a lawyer, had to file his
> nomination papers to contest the 1994 Andhra Pradesh Assembly
> election.
>
> Almost a lifetime since, he had been elected an MLA twice...

A narrative shifts from 1994 to nowadays. And Owaisi is represented as a mature politician and a lawmaker, opposed to a young man struggling to pay his tuition fee. To emphasize a significant time gap as well as a significant change of the character the phrase "Almost a lifetime since" is employed.

It seems to be a shorter form of "Almost a lifetime has passed since then...".
Even though the expression is clearly a metaphorical one it may be taken quite literally because 26 years have passed since 1994, compared to 25 years of age Owaisi was then.

Comment: No. This is an unnecessarily complicated explication. Rjpond has the whole of the answer.

Comment: Rjpond explanation is lucid, indeed. But after all both conclusion ("Almost a lifetime has passed since then..." and "Almost a lifetime ago") seem to me to be similar.